# Detecting Modified Files from Linux User Space

Tags: linux, filesystems, rsync

I need to generate a list of modified files since last list generation on a Linux system. I need to do this on user space, so [FAM](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/fam/) like solutions does not suit for me. To do this, I have some constraints below:

1. Target solution can be used on both `ext2` and `ext3` file systems.
2. Must be implemented on user space, kernel modifications or modules is not allowed.
3. Must not depend on file modification time. It should use at least file size, or better a checksum algorithm to generate [delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_differencing).
4. Does not have to be real time, it will be run periodically (eg. every 10 minutes).

Does anybody know an already implemented solution for this task? I tried using `rsync` for this purpose but it seems `rsync` needs a copy of all files to calculate differences.

**EDIT**

Basically I need a mechanism that genrates a list of files and their deltas recursively under a given directory and compares with the previous ones. It may use file sizes to generate difference or better to use a difference algorithm (similar to [rsync algorithm](http://olstrans.sourceforge.net/release/OLS2000-rsync/OLS2000-rsync.html)). However, cryptographic hash algorithms like MD5 and SHA1 is not suitable for me becasuse of their performance. Please not that I have thousands of thousands files and this is not a cryptographic case.

Real time solutions or solutions that need changes on kernel (like `inotify`, `kqueue`, [FAM](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/fam/), [Fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)) do not also suit for me.

Thank you.

Comment: rsync have -n switch to fake run the command

Comment: @sputnick Does it store differences for future runs even with `-n` switch?

Comment: I added a Python script that may help you. It's damn fast as well. If you have mount points you may want to filter them out to avoid traversing f.e. `/proc`.

Comment: @hochl I am trying your script and will give feedback. Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You may use the `inotify` facility to monitor a filesystem. Not sure
  if there is a tool that already does that, but a **quick search** gives a lot of results, for example https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/.
- You can use `md5sum` to do
  this:

  `find / -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum -b >> /tmp/sums.txt`

  Now you can sort those files and compare them to detect
  differences:

  `sort -k 2 < /tmp/sums.txt > /tmp/sums.sorted.txt`

  I think you get the idea, but of course this will take a **lot** of time since you're checksumming all your data.

**EDIT:** I've written a quick script that dumps a filesystem tree, appending the file size to file names. You can use `diff` to compare the output of two runs to determine what has changed. Of course this is just a scetch and can be improved.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

# initialize variables.
entries=[]
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        rootdir=os.path.normpath(sys.argv[1])
else:
        rootdir=os.curdir

# walk filesystem tree.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for name in sorted(files):
                fullname=os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, name))
                if os.path.islink(fullname) or not os.path.isfile(fullname):
                        entries.append(fullname)
                else:
                        st=os.stat(fullname)
                        entries.append("%s %d" % (fullname, st.st_size))
        for name in sorted(dirs):
                entries.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, name)))

# print sorted list of found filesystem entries.
for entry in sorted(entries):
        print entry
```

Does this help you?

**Suggested improvements:**

- Check if a directory is a mountpoint, and exclude it from the walk.
- prepend type letter to dump, for example `f blub 6` or `d test`, to find changed file types.
- append `st_mtime/st_atime/st_ctime` to files to detect file changes based on time.
- append md5 sum of the first and last 1024 bytes of a file to detect the most common changes (f.e. if the file gets appeneded data).
- append the complete checksum over the contents of a file, for example CRC32.

I hope those suggestions help you create a cool tool ;-)

Comment: Dear hochl, An event queue algorithm like inotify (and some others) may not suit for me since I don't need a real time solution for performance reasons. As of checksumming, basically I need similar to that, but a bit more efficent way. Using MD5 for lots of files and folders may not be suitable since MD5 is a criptographic hash algorithm. Although is is super fast for their own job, it is on the slow side for file differencing.

Comment: Dear hoch, thanks for your effort, but this just generate a list of files and their sizes recursively under a directory. I need a complete and efficent system that generates and maintains (store, compare, differentiate etc.) changes. This is fast for generating list because the commands are already supplied by OS. Storing simple raw list of files and comparing them with `diff` may not be fast enough. Using a properly indexed file to store file info may be required. However I will use your solution and accept your answer until someone else provide a better answer. Thank you.

Comment: @EmreYazıcı: unfortunately, you cannot change the accepted answer anymore (5 minutes is the time window that makes an accept definitive)

Comment: Yes and no, if I edit my response I think he can ... so if you find a better answer I can modify something.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with each file's checksum being recomputed for each run, you could use the simple solution:

```
 find / ( -not -path '/tmp/*' -and -type f ) -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > /tmp/current-listing
 diff /tmp/old-listing /tmp/current-listing
 mv /tmp/current-listing /tmp/old-listing
```

Comment: Dear thiton, generation a checksum for each run is not acceptable for me since I have lots of files and folders. In addition, using MD5 as a checksum algorithm may not be suitable in this case (non-cryptographic) because it's relatively slow for a file difference algorithm. Your solution is definitly suitable for some other cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at

- tripwire
- rkhunter
- rsync (but you'll have to have a reference copy)

rdiffbackup and rsnapshot are fullblown incremental (deltifying) backup solutions based on rsync.

You might also have a lot of use in zfs-fuse or [zfsonlinux](http://zfsonlinux.org). These filesystems support continuous snapshotting:

```
 SNAPID=$RANDOM # something unique, please
 zfs snapshot tank/volume_of_mount@$SNAPID
 zfs send -i tank/volume_or_mount@previous tank/volume_of_mount@$SNAPID |
     pbzip2 > dumpfile.$SNAPID.bz2
```

Receiving end:

```
 zfs receive -vFdn tank2/into_this@$SNAPID < dumpfile.$SNAPID.bz2
```

This kind of snapshotting can be done on-the-fly, live and performs very well, as ZFS is a log-structured filesystem with builtin merkel-tree based integrity checks.

Comment: Dear sehe, I am not looking for a backup solution. Fuse like solutions need kernel modifications which violate some of my constraints.

Comment: @EmreYazıcı: I hope that doesn't mean that you ignored tripwire and rkhunter. Reading your extra comments, I get the strong impression that tripwire is _exactly_ what you are looking for. (ZFS just _happens_ to have my preference - but my answer was broad and mentions a lot of great tools suited for different goals, not just backup. You'll find that I don't even mention backup until _after_ the bullet list.)

Comment: If you let go of the ext2/3 requirement you can use the versioning feature of btrfs ...